# How to find the physical coordinates of window on desktop, and save it as an image

Tags: c#, winapi, coordinates, ocr, tesseract

I have an application in C# that needs to use OCR to read labels and text controls.

The window I need to get a hold of is a real PITA to work with; I can't Spy++ or anything to just get handles to the controls because the application I need to read from has an embedded CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) window widget.  I can get the main window by title and get the handle, but it stops there; I can't get a handle to the CEF control or work with it in any way, I have to get a snapshot of the window (just the window, not the whole desktop in the background).

The issue I have is finding the Window's size and location on the desktop. My theory is that I could capture the image of the window I need to work with containing the CEF control, and use client relative coordinates to set up a RECT that I can pass to OCR for finding a text string there for me to work with.

I should just be able to get a handle to the main window, and get a RECT, and find out where it is and its size, for example:

```
// Get the window rectangle in screen coordinates
RECT windowRect;
GetWindowRect(hWnd, out windowRect);

// Calculate the position of the client area in screen coordinates
Point screenPoint = ...?
ClientToScreen(hWnd, ref screenPoint); ?
```

Or something like that, and it kind of works, but the image has some of the desktop in the background (it starts at top left of desktop, instead of the window I want), and the image is clipped, it's not wide or tall enough, like it has no idea what the size of the window is.

It makes me think I have to deal with screen scaling and DPI too, and on the system the application will run on, the screen's scaling is 1.5 and 144 DPI, the resolution is 2240 x 1400.  I don't know what to make of that.

I have tried some tools to get client coordinates of the controls I'm interested in which are in the CEF control, but doing a simple translation of client to physical screen coordinates to get its X, Y and width, height to get an image, then feed the image into OCR to get the text just doesn't work out; the physical coordinates are close, but wrong.

Does anyone know how to get the position and size of a Window on the desktop, given its handle, so I can capture an image of just the application window?  Then somehow it should just work if I have the relative client coordinates of controls on the window somewhere, from 0, 0 of the main application window, so I can capture images of controls on the screen given their relative X, Y locations and width and height, for OCR to extract text.

Thanks for any help!

I've tried everything I can think of for two weeks; locating the window handle, and trying to discover its location and size on the desktop to get an image.  And then to translate the known client coordinates of controls within the window so I can image those, and feed the image to Tesseract to extract text from them (labels, text boxes, most of them read-only and greyed out).

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) is in all likelihood a better solution to the problem.

Comment: Hmm, I am actually using UI Automation to control the program, so I will take you up on that suggestion and have the OCR done in the UIAutomation instead of a separate program, because client-to-screen coordinates are actually accurate in the UIAutomation program; I have no idea why it works there and not in other programs.

Comment: In all likelihood, you don't need to do any costly/unreliable OCR. UI Automation will provide the raw text data as well. Use the [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) tool to see what data is available through UI Automation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I can't use the Inspect tool with the CEF window, it gives nothing.  It's locked down in there somewhere and I can't even enumerate all Windows handles and use that to find controls, I only get the Windows minimize, maximize and close buttons, that's it.  Also I am sure I have solved the problem now, I was using a console program to test, and after moving to a Win Forms app, and using UI Automation, all I need to do is ClientToScreen coordinates and specify a rectangle and I can read the text I need.